# Is there a way to mute OS X for a set time?

Tags: macos, audio, automation

I'd like to be able to mute the sound for a specified number of seconds and have it come back on automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using AppleScript:

```
set volume with output muted
delay 5
set volume without output muted
```

osascript lets you run AppleScript from a shell:

```
osascript -e "set volume with output muted" -e "delay 5" -e "set volume without output muted"
```

‘5’ is the number of seconds of delay.

Comment: Boss! I made a shell alias so I can enter this command in 3 characters.

Comment: Good trick to avoid Spotify and all other adverts for a minute (: To make it ideal, you can do it using keyboard shortcut - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote